# Ветвления в Си, вопрос по реализации

Tags: c, алгоритм

Привет.

Пишу код под МК, к ногам которого будут прицеплены цифровые датчики. Код должен выплоняться последовательно, в один момент задействован один датчик, он является своеобразным вентилем, решающим, с какого датчика дальше будет считываться инфа и какая ветвь выполняться. Инфа, считанная с датчика, хранению не подлежит. Кода для этого будет совсем немного, строк 100 максимум.

Я не программист, поэтому вижу одно решение, и оно, наверное, неудачное -
это разделение всей логической схемы по автономным блокам - функциям, и переход между ними чем-то типа goto (а чем еще?).

Покритикуйте. Спасибо.

Вот 'набросок' кода http://pastebin.com/h1r8YQWd

Comment: У Вас сложность с обычным if?

    if (вентиль) {
      /* первый случай */
    } else {
      /* второй случай */
    }

Comment: Ну, я на нем и думал изначально. Просто, может быть, есть другие варианты, так как там получается много вложенных if-else.

Comment: @alal, напишите так, как Вам не нравится, и выложите. Тогда, возможно, Вам помогут автоматизировать.

Comment: > так как там получается много вложенных if-else

3-4 вложенных - да, это многовато, нужно выделять внутренности в функции. Но главное не дойти до 128 вложений - тут уже даже в visual studio ругается:)

Comment: Добавлена ссылка на примерный код в вопросе.

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что этот код не компилируется?

Comment: @alal, ну, прямо скажем -- код из пастебина -- это совсем не программа на Си... (так переходить по `goto` можно на метки внутри функции, но не из одной функции на другую (это принципиальное непонимание)).

--

Сенсоры и логику действий (в смысле псевдокода) Вы всю описали? 

(Хотя, лучше бы простыми русскими словами обрисовали алгоритм опроса и действий при определенных сочетаниях сигналов (кстати, а что насчет тайминга?)).

--

А также, я совсем не понял, что все-таки Вы имели в виду в стр. 41 внутри "функции" `final(void)`. Что означает комментарий "тут выход"? 

Выйти из "`main`" ?

Answer (score 4):

[[@alal](/users/22911/alal)](/users/22911/alal), а вообще Ваша задача это типичный конечный автомат (state machine).

Соответственно, при адекватном описании структуры `struct state { ... };`,

(наверное, что-то вроде

```
 struct state {
   struct state *jmp[2];
   int sensor;
 };
```

), описывающей состояние, элементарное действие в нем (чтение нужного сенсора или запись и выход) и переходы из этого состояния в 2 других (по 0 или 1), весь код (после инициализации структур

```
 struct state red_block1 = {{0, 0}, 2},
              start = {{&red_block1, 0}, 1}, 
              sensor_0_1 = {{0, &start}, 0}, 
             ....;

 // заполним поля в struct .jmp[], которые ссылаются "вперед"
 red_block1.jmp[0] = &final; red_block1.jmp[1] = &sensor_0_2;
 start.jmp[1] = &sensor_0_1;
 ....
```

) сводится к паре строк:

```
  struct state *current_state = &start;
  while (current_state = run_state(current_state));
```

и написанию пары функций

```
struct state *run_state(struct state *p) {
  if (p->sensor < 0) { // конец
     write ... 
     return 0;
  }
  return p->jmp[read_sensor(p->sensor)];
}
```

и

```
int read_sensor (int sensor_id) { ... return result; }
```

--

Сейчас уже поздновато... Если интересно, то постараюсь завтра написать поподробнее (с каким-нибудь примерчиком).

Вот пример такой машины состояний.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct state {
  const char *msg; // для наглядности demo
  struct state *jmp[2];
  int code, sensor;
};

/*
  Макрос для описания состояния.
  При описании состояния запишем в .jmp[] вместо адресов номера состояний,
  а при инициализации машины заменим их действующими адресами.
*/
#define STATE(code,msg,s0,s1,sensor) {msg, {(struct state *)(long)(s0), (struct state *)(long)(s1)}, code, sensor}

// номера состояний
#define START 1
#define END 2
#define S1 3
#define S2 4

// моделируем чтение сенсора вводом с клавиатуры
int
read_sensor (const char *msg, int sensor)
{
  printf("state %s: read sensor %d > ", msg, sensor); fflush(stdout);
  char buf[1000];
  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
  int  c = (buf[0] == '1');

  return c;
}

struct state *
run_state (struct state *state)
{
  if (state->sensor >= 0)
    return state->jmp[read_sensor(state->msg, state->sensor)];

  printf ("%s: final state\n", state->msg);
  return 0;
}

void
init_machine (struct state *a[], int n)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      if ((long)a[i]->code == (long)a[j]->jmp[0])
        a[j]->jmp[0] = a[i];
      if ((long)a[i]->code == (long)a[j]->jmp[1])
        a[j]->jmp[1] = a[i];
    }
  }
}

/*
  Пример:
  3 состояния, переходы по 0, 1

  START -> S1, S2
  S1    -> START, END
  S2    -> S2, S1
  END   - write and exit

 */
int 
main ()
{
  struct state  // определим структуры для всех состояний машины
    start = STATE(START, "main", S1, S2, 1),
    end = STATE(END, "final action & exit", 0, 0, -1),
    s1 = STATE(S1, "s1", START, END, 2),
    s2 = STATE(S2, "s2", S2, S1, 0),
    *state = &start,  // начальное состояние
    // вспомогательный массив для настройки адресов структур в .jmp[]
    *s[] = {&start, &end, &s1, &s2};

  init_machine(s, sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]));
  while (state = run_state(state));

  return puts("Bye") == EOF;
}
```

Проверял в Linux `gcc stmach.c`

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ ./a.out 
state main: read sensor 1 > 1
state s2: read sensor 0 > 0
state s2: read sensor 0 > 1
state s1: read sensor 2 > 0
state main: read sensor 1 > 0
state s1: read sensor 2 > 1
final action & exit: final state
Bye
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Если есть вопросы, спрашивайте.

Comment: @alal, обновил ответ, добавил пример программирования state machine.

Comment: Замечательный пример. Как раз искал способы избежать  ветвлений в C (си) .  Может есть ещё примеры?

Answer (score 1):

1. Обычный switch/case.
2. Или что-то вроде массива указателей на функции, если значение идет с прогрессией

   typedef void (*pfnHandler)(void);

   ```
   void Handler0() {};
   void Handler1() {};

   pfnHandler Handlers[] = {Handler0, Handler1};

   ..
   if (state < sizeof(Handlers)/sizeof(*Handlers))
     Handlers[state]();
   ```

Comment: С прогрессией? Это как? В регистр что-то писать?

Comment: Имелось ввиду, если датчик возвращает значения вроде 0, 1, 2, 3 и т.п. Ну или другие целые числа, идущие "подряд".
Хотя, сдается мне, ваша реализация С не позволит такое сделать.

Comment: Нет, датчики возвращают значения 0 или 1.